# Is the average of two Schur stable matrices also stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, discrete-time

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary real matrices of the same dimension. If they are both Schur stable for discrete-time systems, i.e.,  all eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ have norm strictly less than one, can we know whether the matrix $\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}$ is Schur stable? Some counterexamples or references are appreciated.

I know that the sum of two Hurwitz stable matrices is not necessary to be Hurwitz stable. I also notice that if the two Hurwitz stable matrices are commuting, their sum must be stable. If the answer to my question is no, is there a similar condition for Schur stable matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: As $\frac12I+\frac12I=I$, the answer is clearly negative. Another counterexample: let $J=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and consider $A=J,\,B=J^T$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be 'average' instead of 'sum'. I have edited the question. The second counterexample is still effective. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In general no. However, it is the case when

1. $A$ and $B$ are normal.
2. There exists $T$ such that $T^{-1}AT$ and $T^{-1}BT$ are both upper triangular.
3. $AB=BA$.

Also, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509996/stuck-on-the-formula-of-spectral-radius/3510221#3510221).

For a counter example in the general case let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=A^T$.

Comment: Scalars don't create a problem. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\alpha \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha A$.

Comment: Great answer! Thx a lot. I deleted the previous comments as I noticed this.